# Help to remove tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, torsocks

Last night I installed tor and now i want to delete it and install some new package. I am getting the following error. How do i fix this please help.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server       
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
libevent-core-2.1-6 libhtml-template-perl mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
Suggested packages:
libipc-sharedcache-perl mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libevent-core-2.1-6 libhtml-template-perl mysql-server mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 81 not upgraded.
Need to get 11.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 95.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Ign:1 tor+http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 mysql-server-core-5.7 amd64 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
Err:2 tor+http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libevent-core-2.1-6 amd64 2.1.8-stable-4build1
Unable to connect to localhost:9050:
Ign:3 tor+http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 mysql-server-5.7 amd64 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
Ign:4 tor+http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libhtml-template-perl all 2.97-1
Ign:5 tor+http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 mysql-server all 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
Err:4 tor+http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libhtml-template-perl all 2.97-1
Unable to connect to localhost:9050:
Ign:5 tor+http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 mysql-server all 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
Err:1 tor+http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 mysql-server-core-5.7 amd64 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
Could not connect to localhost:9050 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err:3 tor+http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 mysql-server-5.7 amd64 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
Unable to connect to localhost:9050:
Ign:5 tor+http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 mysql-server all 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
Err:5 tor+http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 mysql-server all 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
Unable to connect to localhost:9050:
E: Failed to fetch tor+http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.7/mysql-server-core-5.7_5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb  Could not connect to localhost:9050 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
E: Failed to fetch tor+http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libe/libevent/libevent-core-2.1-6_2.1.8-stable-4build1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to localhost:9050:
E: Failed to fetch tor+http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.7/mysql-server-5.7_5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to localhost:9050:
E: Failed to fetch tor+http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libh/libhtml-template-perl/libhtml-template-perl_2.97-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to localhost:9050:
E: Failed to fetch tor+http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.7/mysql-server_5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_all.deb  Unable to connect to localhost:9050:
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

i did tried some other settings as well as shown [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/414962/curl-tries-to-connect-to-127-0-0-19050-by-default). I just wanna delete tor fully.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue u need to remove all the `tor+` from every URL shown in `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` Then you will be good to go after `sudo apt-get update`